# Unable to link user controllable parameter to query: DevExpress Report and Dashboard Server

Tags: devexpress, xtrareport

I'm currently working on generating a set of reports and dashboards based on a set of data within our mysql database.

I've created a few custom procedures that take a date input and give all the results as required.

Unfortunately, when I point to these procedures within "data sources", I'm unable to dynamically change the Date parameter - once I set it within Data Source, it's stuck as that date forever (unless I edit the report/dashboard).

Does anyone know of any way you can change the query based on a users input?

I've tried creating parameters which match the name of the parameter set within the query at "Data Source", but have been unable to "inject" the date to use.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just to add to this - it's as though the parameter defined within the query editor/data sources is completely stand-alone, and has no relation to any other parameters throughout the whole report/dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the "Filter a SQL Query"  section of this documentation topic https://docs.devexpress.com/ReportServer/118944/create-dashboards/add-a-dashboard-parameter-and-filter-data

Briefly, you need to create a dashboard/report parameter and bound it to the data source's query parameter via expression.

Comment: Thank you for this - didn't realise you'd have to change a parameter within datasource to be an "expression", which in turn can link to a user defined parameter.